# Securing a POST Request in NodeJS from Backend Application

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, jwt

I'm wanting to receive a POST request sent from a backend java application that sends user account information (e.g. username, email, etc.) and will create an account with the given information. What method can I go about where the api I have can only be used from my java backend (so people can't just start creating accounts themselves)? I assume a method would be using an api key but I have had trouble finding resources on how to implement that. Could someone help me and steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is by the use of API Keys.

- You would have a list of valid clientsIds for your NodeJS Server (`Note that the JAVA backend server would act as a client for your Node JS server when creating users`).
- Along with the list of valid clients, you would also need to store a valid API Key for each client.
- The Java Backend would send you its clientId and the API Key in the POST request. You would need to validate the client id and the API Key for that client.
- Once both are validated, you can assume the request to be from your Java backend.
- Both the list of valid clientIds and the associated API Keys should be stored in environment variables. The API Keys should be different for the same client in different environments.

Another way I have implemented this in the past, and I consider to be more secure, is by use of RS256 Algo JWT Tokens with the use of Public and Private keys.

- Your Java backend should generate a Public/Private key pair and provide the Node backend the public key.
- Along with the POST Request, the Java Backend will generate and sign JWT token using the Private Key and send it to your NodeJS Backend.
- Your NodeJS backend should verify the token using the public key.
- The JWT Token generated by the Java backend should be short lived.
- Every time the Java Backend has to send a POST request, it should generate a new JWT token.

The use of JWTs are more secure as they can be short lived and you dont have to worry about a token being leaked. If the API Key gets leaked, you will have to co-ordinate between the two backends to start using a new API Key. However, if a JWT token gets leaked, the same token cannot be used once it expires. It would be safe to have the JWT token short-lived, may be 1-2 minutes. Since the Private and Public keys are not being sent along with each request, there is a lesser chance of it being leaked.